# overwriting my strings on item click and i can not delete from database

Tags: sqlite

When i press "Lägg till(Add)" i put textin my three edittext boxes, then i'll press OK and it should save it in database and display it in my listview with the first editbox text as tite. When i press on a item in my listview i want to be abel to show inputed text and if i press "RADERA(delete)" i want to be able to delete it from databas and listview.

my database adapter

```
 package com.projekt;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {
    static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    static final String KEY_PASS = "pass";
    static final String KEY_USERNAME = "user";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBPASS";
    static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "information";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table information (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "user text not null, pass text not null, title text not null);";
    final Context context;
    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    // ---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    public long insertInfo(String title, String user, String pass) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, user);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASS, pass);

        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteInfo(long rowId) {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public void delete_byID(int id){
         db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID+"="+id, null);
        }

    public Cursor getAllInfo() {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME,
                KEY_PASS, KEY_TITLE }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getInfo(String title) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASS, KEY_TITLE }, KEY_PASS + "= '" + title + "'",
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public boolean updateInfo(long rowId, String title, String user, String pass) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_USERNAME, user);
        args.put(KEY_PASS, pass);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}

my program

    package com.projekt;

import java.util.ArrayList;

//import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class layout2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {
    Button btn3;
    ListView lv;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    String titleInfo;
    ArrayList<String> nameList;
    EditText anvNamn;
    EditText pass;
    EditText title;
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    String passInfo = ""; 
    String anv = "";
    String titleInfo2 = "";
    String visa;
    int del;
    Cursor c;
    Button btn5;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Start
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.program_layout);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, nameList);
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getAllData();
                //Stop

    }

    private ArrayList<String> getAllData() {

        // ---get all contacts---
        db.open();
        c = db.getAllInfo();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                anv = c.getString(1);
                passInfo = c.getString(2);
                titleInfo2 = c.getString(3);
                //in = new String (anv, passInfo, titleInfo2);
                //nameList.add(in);
                listAdapter.add(titleInfo2);
                //updateList();
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            //listAdapter.add(titleInfo2);
            //del = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_ROWID));
        }
        db.close();
        //listAdapter.add(titleInfo2);
        return nameList;
    }

    public void inputDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LinearLayout lila1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        lila1.setOrientation(1);
        anvNamn = new EditText(this);
        pass = new EditText(this);
        title = new EditText(this);
        lila1.addView(title);
        lila1.addView(anvNamn);
        lila1.addView(pass);

        title.setText("Titel");
        anvNamn.setText("Användarnamn");
        pass.setText("Lösenord");
        alert.setView(lila1);

        title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                title.setText("");
            }
        });

        anvNamn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                anvNamn.setText("");
            }
        });

        pass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pass.setText("");
            }
        });



        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                String titleDB = title.getText().toString();
                String userDB = anvNamn.getText().toString();
                String passDB = pass.getText().toString();

                listAdapter.add(titleDB);

                db.open();  
                db.insertInfo(titleDB, userDB, passDB);
                db.close();
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alert.show();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button3:
            inputDialog();
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(nextActivity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String text = nameList.get(arg2);
        //final int ar = arg2;
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle(titleInfo2);
        alert.setMessage("Användarnamn: " + anv + "\nLösenord: "+ passInfo);
        final String radera = listAdapter.getItem(arg2).toString();
        final long raderaPos = listAdapter.getItemId(arg2);


        alert.setNegativeButton("RADERA",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        //String s = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                        db.open();
                        //db.updateInfo(arg2, anv, passInfo, titleInfo);
                        db.deleteInfo(arg2);
                        db.updateInfo(arg2, anv, passInfo, titleInfo);
                        db.close();
                        listAdapter.remove(radera); 
                    }
                });
        alert.show();
    }

}

im from sweden my string names may be confusing.
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: what should i do in my code to make it work as as described

Answer (score 0):

Never ever use parameter names like `arg0`,`1`,...
It is impossible to understand code that uses such names.

Apparently, in some places, the code uses `arg2` (the position of the view in the adapter) where it should use `arg3` (the item's row id).